# find for which account the email is received when it is a BCC Mail

Tags: c#, vba, outlook, outlook-addin

I am having an outlook pst where email for "aperson@domian.com" account and "bperson@domain.com" account will be received. i need to process all new emails that received to "aperson@domian.com" account. Basically for normal email (i.e., marking address in TO or CC field) we check the TO field of the email for which account the email is received.  For BCC Mails (i.e., marking address in BCC field) we cannot able to check the account. Because in the TO field it may contain Undisclosed recipient or Sender email address. i had checked the internet header of those mails. i come to know that the "aperson@domian.com" is there in some X-Header fields based on the SMTP which it received.

is there any way to find for which account the email is received (if it is a bcc mail)?
is there any way to read the Outlook - internet header programmatically in c#?

Answer (score -1):

Sure, you can read the account name and stamp using `MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`.
The DASL name of the account name property is 
`http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8580001F`

You can also read the MIME headers from the `PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS` property (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001F`) - look at the messages with [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy/home.htm) (I am its author) to see the available properties.